# Puzzling a covered region from list of subregions

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a long list of values x and y, sorted by the value of the x value. I would like to output a list of longest continuous spans of the x and y values. This is a bit difficult to put to words but will hopefully become clear with the following example:

```
0, 148
0, 145
0, 186
0, 5768
600, 2374
2376, 2415
3000, 4315
6000, 6616
6000, 6799
6000, 7262
```

As the area between 5768 and 6000 is not covered by any of the entries, the above should output:

```
0, 5768
6000, 7262
```

This seems to me like it should be a simple problem and yet I've been working on it for a while without a solution. I've posted my code below. 
The problem with my current efforts is that while the x values are sorted, it is possible that the x value of line k exceeds the y value of line k-1 but does not mark the beginning of a new continuous string.

```
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in open('test')]
myarray=[]
for line in lines:
    myarray.append(line.split(', '))

def findCoveredRegions(regionArray):
    resultsContigs = []
    j = regionArray[0][1]
    i = regionArray[0][0]
    for line in regionArray:
        last_i = i
        i = line[0]
        if i <= j:
            if line[1] > j:
                j = line[1]
        else:
            resultsContigs.append([last_i,j])
    resultsContigs.append([i,regionArray[len(regionArray)-1][1]])

    return resultsContigs

print findCoveredRegions(myarray)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem, even with the example. If you are finding it hard to put into words then you will almost surely find it hard to put into code. Maybe work on that first.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by: 1) "longest continuous spans of the x and y values" 2) "the area between 5768 and 6000 is not covered"

Comment: Imagine you have all the numbers between 0 and 7262 in a continuous sequence. We can think of each line in my example as a string of all the numbers between 0 and 148, 0 to 145 etc. 
What I want to produce is a list of regions between 0 and 7262 the numbers of which would appear at least once, knowing that some numbers would not appear at all. 
The numbers between 5768 and 6000 are not a part of any of the sub-sequences but all the numbers between 0 and 5768 and 6000 and 7262 are 'covered' by at least one of the regions. 
Does that make sense?

Comment: In mathematical terms you are basically asking for the union of a set of intervals, expressed as a strictly increasing set of intervals. In other words as few intervals as possible. Is that correct? Interesting problem, I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a numpy solution

```
myarray = np.asanyarray(myarray)
order = np.argsort(myarray.ravel())
coverage = np.add.accumulate(1 - 2*(order%2))
gaps = np.where(coverage==0)[0]
left = order[np.r_[0, gaps[:-1] + 1]]
right = order[gaps]
result = myarray.ravel()[np.c_[left, right]]
```

It pools and sorts all boundaries. Then goes from left to right counting how many left (+1) and right (-1) boundaries it has encountered. This number will never be negative and only fall to zero where there is a gap. From the locations of gaps the covered intervals are reconstructed.

Comment: This does not seem to give the right solution to the test case that I provided. I get the following output:
[['0' '2374']
 ['2376' '2415']
 ['3000' '4315']
 ['5768' '600']
 ['6000' '7262']]

Comment: Indeed, it checks _adjacent_ intervals, but it must check the last covered interval, which may contain some of the intervals following it completely.

Comment: @Sigurgeir I do get the right result, provided I convert the strings to ints. It doesn't work for you because of '600' > '5768' as strings etc., which, of course, completely trips up the algo.

Comment: @9000 Nope, the sorting takes care of all that.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: cool! (And your solution, while in spirit being APL, is much more readable.)

Comment: @PaulPanzer. You're right. I was indeed comparing strings. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @9000 Thanks. I'd never heard of APL before, had to look it up. That special keyboard layout they show on wikipedia is actually quite amusing.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: You should also take a look at its modern ascii-friendly descendants, J and [K](http://www.math.bas.bg/bantchev/place/k.html).

Answer (score 2):

This won't be particularly fast, but I think it's quite Pythonic and readable. It doesn't require or use sorted lists of intervals.

```
intervals = [(0, 148),
 (0, 145),
 (0, 186),
 (0, 5768),
 (600, 2374),
 (2376, 2415),
 (3000, 4315),
 (6000, 6616),
 (6000, 6799),
 (6000, 7262)]


def intersect(interval_a, interval_b):
    """Return whether two intervals intersect"""
    (a_bottom, a_top), (b_bottom, b_top) = interval_a, interval_b
    return a_bottom <= b_top and b_bottom <= a_top


def union_one_one(interval_a, interval_b):
    """Return the union of two intervals"""
    (a_bottom, a_top), (b_bottom, b_top) = interval_a, interval_b
    return min(a_bottom, b_bottom), max(a_top, b_top)


def union_many_one(old_intervals, new_interval):
    """Return the union of a new interval with several old intervals."""
    result = []
    for old_interval in old_intervals:
        # If an old interval intersects with the new interval, merge the old interval into the new one.
        if intersect(old_interval, new_interval):
            new_interval = union_one_one(old_interval, new_interval)    
        # Otherwise, leave the old interval alone.
        else:
            result.append(old_interval)
    result.append(new_interval)
    return result


def union_all(intervals):
    """Return the union of a collection of intervals"""
    result = []
    for interval in intervals:
        result = union_many_one(result, interval)
    return result            


print(union_all(intervals))
```

Comment: Nice. Of course, it has O(n^2) worst case, but in some scenarios (lots of overlap) it may even be faster than the sorting solution.